# Java new socket connection vs keep-alive

Tags: java, ssl, tcp, nio, keep-alive

I am building TCP/TLS server for IoT network. I am using Java NIO with Reactor pattern to achieve non-blocking always ready to serve server. Some of the server actions can take up to several seconds so I opted to use NIO with worker threads. What is better? Keeping large number of mostly idle connections (it will be more than 10000 connections) or would it be better to force open connection for each request? What is more scalable and more perfomant? I tried to search it but I couldn't find Java comparison using NIO.

Comment: I would like to know why is this a bad question or why I received -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research and tryout on my testing env I decided to go concurrent way. I benchmarked it is less overhead using concurrent connection rather than create new connection every 5 seconds. I set up the linux similar to the MigratoryData server.

Source:
My benchmark
MigratoryData Solving 10M problem ( https://mrotaru.wordpress.com/2015/05/20/how-migratorydata-solved-the-c10m-problem-10-million-concurrent-connections-on-a-single-commodity-server/ )